# Check string for defined format and get part of it

Tags: php, regex

How can I check if a string has the format `[group|any_title]` and give me the title back?

```
[group|This is] -> This is
[group|just an] -> just an
[group|example] -> example
```

I would do that with `explode` and `[group|` as the delimiter and remove the last `]`. If length (of explode) is > 0, then the string has the correct format.

But I think that is not quite a good way, isn't it?

Comment: Show us what you've tried and explain what the issue is please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to check if a string matches a regex?

```
if(preg_match('/^\[group\|(.+)\]$/', $string, $m)) {
   $title = $m[1];
}
```

If the `group` part is supposed to be dynamic as well:

```
if(preg_match('/^\[(.+)\|(.+)\]$/', $string, $m)) {
   $group = $m[1];
   $title = $m[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) matching using PHP function [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

You can use for example [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com) to create and test a regular expression and when you're done, then implement it in your PHP script (replace the first parameter of `preg_match` with your regular expression):

```
$text = '[group|This is]';
// replace "pattern" with regular expression pattern
if (preg_match('/pattern/', $text, $matches)) {
    // OK, you have parts of $text in $matches array
}
else {
    // $text doesn't contain text in expected format
}
```

Specific regular expression pattern depends on how strictly you want to check your input string. It can be for example something like `/^\[.+\|(.+)\]$/` or `/\|([A-Za-z ]+)\]$/`. First checks if string starts with `[`, ends with `]` and contains any characters delimited by `|` in between. Second one just checks if string ends with `|` followed by upper and lower case alphabetic characters and spaces and finally `]`.

Comment: `preg_match('/^\[.+\|(.+)\]$/', $text, $matches)`?

Comment: Nice. You were very fast. Yep, this could work. Also something like this: `/\|([A-Za-z ]+)\]$/`. It depends what your title can contain and how strict you want to be with matching. Your regexp matches title containing any characters, my matches upper and lower case alphabetic characters and space only. Also my doesn't check part before pipe, so there can be whatever.

Comment: How is  `'pattern'` a regular expression pattern?

Comment: @PHPglue Read my answer, please.

Comment: You should display that as a variable then, so you don't confuse anyone.

Comment: @PHPglue I hope that people who are less angry and mean and better read questions and answers won't be confused.